# MySQL Special Sorting

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

I have a field in my (`MySQL`) Database that has invoice numbers in this format: `024/14`

The `024` part is an automatic increment handled from the code, not from the database, and the `14` is actually the Year.

Is there a way to sort by this field, having in mind that the year's number comes last, without having to restructure the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select inv_number from yourtable order by substring(inv_number, 5, 2), substring(inv_number, 1, 3)
```

Comment: That is almost correct, Sir, Inspired by this answer I could get it right, by aknowledging `substring()` in mySQL. It should be `substring(str, 5)` or `substring(str, 5, 2)`, but I needed to sort by `substring(str, 1, 3)` as a second sorting criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try this select:

```
select * from table_name order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_name, '/', 1);
```

where field_name - your field with invoices numbers.